# Fix React Warning: Unknown prop on <> tag. Remove this prop from the element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got a warning:

```
Warning: Unknown props `onClickProp`, `excludedClickClasses`
 on <div> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details,
 see `https://...react-unknown-prop in div` (created by myTable)
```

I did some search, but still can't find a solution. I didn't use these two props in `myTable`. in `myTable`, I just passed it in the child component `myTableRow`.

I tried to define props types and default props, but it doesn't work. Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already taken a look at the link that is in the warning?

Comment: That warning is happening because you're passing `onClickProp`, etc to a `div` element in one of your components. A `div` element by default doesn't have those props, so these props would be no-op, and as such a warning.

Comment: Even if it where a button, shouldn't it be `onClick` rather than `onClickProp`?

Comment: @technophyle Thanks, the issue is fixed. Do you want to post it as answer?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning is happening because you're passing `onClickProp`, etc to a `div` element in one of your components.

A `div` element by default doesn't have those props, so these props would be no-op, and as such a warning.

You can find the detailed [documentation here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html).